# get facebook list of liked page by category

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I get code this from facebook developers

```
$this->api('/ USER_ID /likes');
```

But how I get the list based on its category using php-sdk. I have checked the Graph API Explorer but the modifiers only `limit, offset, target_id`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible with the graph api. But you could easily create you own array

```
$ordered_by_cat = array();
foreach($results['data'] as $result){
     $ordered_by_cat[$result['category'] = $result
}
```

Given that $results is your json response